# How can I award a bounty to another user's question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I read about Altruist Badge, but I can't see how could it be applied.

What are the requirements for this badge to happen?

Do I have access to another person's question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounties can be awarded by anyone with a reputation greater than 75 and the amount of bounty to offer, to any question **asked by anyone two days after the question has been asked**. To award bounty to a question, just click on `start a bounty` button just below the question.

[image: question asked by someone, not me]

Comment: thanks @Jobin That was the right answer

Comment: @kamil: Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/232872):

> #### How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was
>   asked.
>
> To start a bounty, click on the <kbd>start a bounty</kbd> link at the
>   bottom of an eligible question.  The bounty panel will open.  Use the
>   dropdown to allocate the bounty amount -- anywhere between 50 and 500
>   reputation, in 50 point increments.
>
> You must have at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, and at least
>   as much reputation as the bounty amount.
>
> The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the
>   bounty is *started*, not when it is awarded.